# Classifying images with Vision and CoreML in macOS

Tags: macos, ibm-watson, coreml, apple-vision

I have trained IBM Watson to recognize objects of interest. Since remote execution isn’t a requirement I want to export to .mlmodel with the tool provided and run in macOS.

Unfortunately learning Swift and macOS development isn’t a requirement either. It is possible to invoke Vision directly from the command line or from a scripting language? As alternative anybody knows a skeleton of macOS app to run Vision over a list of files and obtain classification scores in tabular form? Thanks.

Comment: Have you been able to do this successfully? I am looking to do the same thing but having no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The code mentioned in this [article](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/detecting-avengers-superheroes-in-your-ios-app-with-ibm-watson-and-coreml-fe38e493a4d1) uses a downloaded Core ML model in an iOS App through Watson SDK.

Additionally, Here’s a code sample that uses Watson Visual Recognition and Core ML to classify images. The workspace has two projects

- Core ML Vision Simple: Classify images locally with Visual Recognition.
- Core ML Vision Custom: Train a custom Visual Recognition model for more specialized classification.

Refer the code and instructions [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/visual-recognition-coreml/blob/master/README.md)

Also, there’s a starter kit that comes with Watson Visual Recognition preconfigured with Core ML - https://console.bluemix.net/developer/appledevelopment/starter-kits/custom-vision-model-for-core-ml-with-watson

Comment: Used Core ML Vision Simple to generate a minimal iOS app for recognition one image at a time. It works but I am looking for something for macOS. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also load the mlmodel into Python and use the coremltools package to make predictions. I wouldn't use that in a production environment, but it's OK to get something basic up and running.

Comment: Isn’t clear from the description how prediction works. Would I be able to pass images to it through Vision? Thanks for sharing.

Comment: From your Python code you'd load the mlmodel file into an `MLModel` object, then call `mlmodel.predict{"image": img}` where `img` is a PIL image object. The result is a dictionary with the classification results.